# Call nib method from ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, nib

Tell me please what I do wrong. I have a instance of *nib file in ViewController. ViewController implements UITextFieldDelegate. In the delegate method "textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange" I call method written in *nib class. In *nib class I have a User object initialised, but in the method ViewController calls User object is nil...

Here is the code..

```
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.usersTableView = [[UsersTableView alloc] init];

// Call delegate method
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

[self.usersTableView searchTextFieldDidChange:searchString];

}
```

***Nib class**

```
#import "User.h"    

@interface UsersTableView()
@property (nonatomic) User *user;
@end


- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {

    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {

    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"UsersTableView" owner:self options:nil];

    [self addSubview:self.view];
    self.user = [[User alloc] init];
  }
     return self;
}

.....Anyware [self testMethod];

- (void)testMethod {
    NSLog (@"%@", self.user) // user object exist
}

// Method called from ViewController

- (void)searchTextFieldDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

    NSLog (@"%@", self.user) // user object is nil...
}
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: have you attached delegate from storyboard ?

Comment: check the files owner and and the delegate of the textfield

Comment: Hai , did you display the text string in textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange.. And please put return yes bcs that is non void method.

Answer (score 1):

I see many errors in your implementation. Please let me correct them one by one.

```
-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {       
           self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
           if (self) {

           [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"UsersTableView" owner:self options:nil];

           [self addSubview:self.view];
           self.user = [[User alloc] init];
         }
            return self;    }
```

loadNibNamed: method will return a UIView* array. If you want to use views from your nib, then you need to use its return value.

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {

        self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
        if (self) {

        NSArray* viewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"UsersTableView" owner:self options:nil];

        [self addSubview:[viewArray firstObject]];
        self.user = [[User alloc] init];
      }
         return self;
    }
```

2. Custom class initialization:

You create your tableView with a simple alloc init, which doesn't call initWithCoder method.

self.usersTableView = [[UsersTableView alloc] init];

I think you should implement the `- (instancetype)init` method, and put you custom view initialisation there.

```
-(instancetype)init{        
            self = [super init];
            if (self) {

            NSArray* viewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"UsersTableView" owner:self options:nil];

            [self addSubview:[viewArray firstObject]];
            self.user = [[User alloc] init];
          }
             return self;
        }
```

I hope it will help, and it will work.

Comment: I load external *nib into UIView in the ViewController in Storyboard. Method you told me - `NSArray* viewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"UsersTableView" owner:self options:nil];

        [self addSubview:[viewArray firstObject]];` don't show the table view in UIView. I have a IBOutlet connection to the tableView in *nib class and this reference  in nil ...

Comment: Could you please check what is the first view in the array? If it's the required tableView, then check it's frame. I think its frame is not valid. Try
UIView* firstView = [viewArray firstObject];
firstView.frame = self.bounds;
[self addSubview:firstView];

Comment: The first object of viewArray is UIView.  UIView: 0x7b63b2e0; frame = (0 0; 320 447); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b63b3a0

Comment: In the `- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder` method all views an objects (UITableView and UserTableView instance) initialized correct. The problem is when I call method written in UsersTableView.m from UIViewController, all Objects are nil...  anyway, thanks for help! If you want to see the project, here is the link to github -> https://github.com/makedonskii/Keyboard.git

Comment: I've checked the code, and I've found the problem, would you like to describe the problem here, or may I make a pull request with some comments?

Comment: Thank you very much! You  can you make pull request with comments. Again, thanks !!

Comment: I can't push my changes to github, so I have created a patch file. How can I send it to you?

Comment: You can send my file via email. sasha_fadeev@list.ru Or if you want describe problem here...

Answer (score 0):

initWithCoder gets called only when you instantiate a view controller from story board. Unfortunately, In your case user object is getting initialised inside initWithCoder and you are using init to create the instance of viewcontroller.

Try loading viewcontroller from story board.

```
 UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewController"];
```

or if you want to load view controller from xib use

```
NSArray *subviewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Your_nib_name" owner:self options:nil];
UIView *mainView = [subviewArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

If you are still not satisfied override init of your nib class and instantiate user object inside init method though I wont prefer doing that :)

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewContoller alloc]init];
vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewController"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES complited:nil];
```

Comment: Please describe how is it a solution for the problem mentioned.